# Python Tkitner : unknown option "-height". Can't change the size of button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, layout

I am trying to make a simple program using tkinter.

I was trying to change font or style of width or height. 
width can be changed but when it comes to height or font - it shows mistake. 
I am thinking - maybe it can be because the layout?
(The button that is changed in width is in the bottom of def initUI)

Also in case anyone can also answer this question:
I made 1 frame red because there will be error messages there but does anyone know how to make this red lie less in width?

Thank you in

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__()

        master.minsize(width=350, height=160)
        master.maxsize(width=650, height=500)

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Hank (version 3)")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)

        #dataset
        lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="Dataset file_name", width=18)
        lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        entryDataset= Entry(frame1)
        entryDataset.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        #row col begin
        frame2 = Frame(self)
        frame2.pack(fill=X)

        lblRow = Label(frame2, text="Row", width=6)
        lblRow.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        entryRow = Entry(frame2, width=5)
        entryRow.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0, expand=True)

        lblCol = Label(frame2, text="Column", width=7.5)
        lblCol.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        entryCol = Entry(frame2, width=5)
        entryCol.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, expand=True)

        lblBegin = Label(frame2, text="Start at", width=6)
        lblBegin.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        entryBegin = Entry(frame2, width=5)
        entryBegin.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0, expand=True)

        #console window
        s = Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background='grey')

        frame3 = Frame(self, style='My.TFrame')
        frame3.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        #button start and help
        s = Style()
        s.configure('My.ConsoleFrame', background='red')

        frame4 = Frame(self)
        frame4.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        startbutton = Button(frame4, text="Start Clustering", height="100", width="100")
        startbutton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x160+300+160")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the prime examples of why global imports are bad.
You write at the top:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

This means that you import everything from `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` into your `main.py` namespace. Then you write for example:

```
frame3 = Frame(self, bg="grey")
....
lblCol = Label(frame2, text="Column", width=7)
```

These are Frame/Label objects, but which ones? The one in `tkinter` or the one in `tkinter.ttk`? If it is the first, you will have to set the height with `-height`, else you will have to use `tkinter.ttk.Style()`. Same with the `-bg` for the frame.

Solution:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__()

        master.minsize(width=350, height=160)
        master.maxsize(width=650, height=500)

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Hank (version 3)")
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=tk.X)

        #dataset
        lbl1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Dataset file_name", width=18)
        lbl1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        entryDataset= tk.Entry(frame1)
        entryDataset.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, expand=True)

        #row col begin
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame2.pack(fill=tk.X)

        lblRow = tk.Label(frame2, text="Row", width=6)
        lblRow.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        entryRow = tk.Entry(frame2, width=5)
        entryRow.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=0, expand=True)

        lblCol = tk.Label(frame2, text="Column", width=7)
        lblCol.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        entryCol = tk.Entry(frame2, width=5)
        entryCol.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, expand=True)

        lblBegin = tk.Label(frame2, text="Start at", width=6)
        lblBegin.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        entryBegin = tk.Entry(frame2, width=5)
        entryBegin.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=0, expand=True)

        frame3 = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey")
        frame3.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        frame4 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame4.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        startbutton = tk.Button(frame4, text="Start Clustering", height="100", width="100")
        startbutton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x160+300+160")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I did it here with the `tkinter` widgets. You can obviously do `import tkinter.ttk as ttk` and rewrite the code using those, it is just a matter of taste.