# How To Display Popup Message in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Currently have two functions, one to display for a win and one for a loss. I think I have it coded to where a popup occurs with a message and a button, but not exactly how I want it to be. I want the pop up to come up in the center of the screen, make the button larger, as well as the popup. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk  # popup window
from tkinter import ttk  # popup window


def animate_win():
  reg_font = ("Verdana", 22)
  msg = "You WON!"
  popup = tk.Tk()
  popup.wm_title("Result")
  popup.geometry("500x500")
  text = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=reg_font)
  text.pack(side="top")
  b1 = ttk.Button(popup, text=":)", command=popup.destroy)
  b1.pack()
  popup.mainloop()

def animate_loss():
  reg_font = ("Verdana", 22)
  msg = "You LOST!"
  popup = tk.Tk()
  popup.wm_title("Result")
  popup.geometry("500x500")
  text = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=reg_font)
  text.pack(side="top")
  b1 = ttk.Button(popup, text=":(", command=popup.destroy)
  b1.pack()
  popup.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using duplicated   popup = tk.Tk() and popup.mainloop()? You can used one script for both functions.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should resize your popup window and the button, I suppose you had problems with defining height and width beacuse of imports done as following:

```
import tkinter as tk  # popup window
from tkinter import ttk  # popup window
```

In this code snippet second import is redundant and you should probbably avoid the second import in your code aswell. Check the following discusion:

[Python Tkitner : unknown option "-height". Can't change the size of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726189/python-tkitner-unknown-option-height-cant-change-the-size-of-button)

```
import tkinter as tk  # popup window



def animate_win():
  reg_font = ("Verdana", 22)
  msg = "You WON!"
  popup = tk.Tk()
  
  popup.minsize(800, 600) #
  
  popup.wm_title("Result")
  popup.geometry("500x500")
  text = tk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=reg_font)
  text.pack(side="top")
  b1 = tk.Button(popup, text=":)", command=popup.destroy)
  
  b1.config(height = 20, width = 150) #
  
  
  b1.pack()
  popup.mainloop()

def animate_loss():
  reg_font = ("Verdana", 22)
  msg = "You LOST!"
  popup = tk.Tk()

  popup.minsize(800, 600) #
  
  popup.wm_title("Result")
  popup.geometry("500x500")
  text = tk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=reg_font)
  text.pack(side="top")
  b1 = tk.Button(popup, text=":(", command=popup.destroy)
  
  b1.config(height = 20, width = 150) #
  
  b1.pack()
  popup.mainloop()
```

With this error out of the way, resizing the popup window and button is simple, only thing left to do is centering the window, for which I would direct you to the following discussion:

[Tkinter Make My Pop Up Window in Middle of the Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73184529/tkinter-make-my-pop-up-window-in-middle-of-the-screen)